# How to connect to postgres in Linode from local system

Tags: python, postgresql, linode

I have a python script to add data to a postgres database. During testing, I had created a database in the localsystem and it worked perfectly. Now I have the database running in linode. I am not sure how to connect to the database from the localsytem. I have the database details stored in a python file as follows

```
DATABASE = 'my_database'
HOST = <IP_ADDRESS> # the ip_address of the linode instance
PORT = '5432'
USER = 'database_user'
PASSWORD = 'database_password'
```

I use the above code in access the database. in case of the database running in the localhost, the host was equal to `HOST = 'localhost'`.

When I run the python script from the localsystem to connect to the database this is the message I get

```
psycopg2.OperationalError: connection to server at "<IP_ADDESS>", port 5432 failed: Connection refused
    Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
```

I am not sure how to connect to the database running in linode.

Comment: A) The server `listen_addresses` in `postgresql.conf` is not set correctly. See [Connections](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-connection.html) and/or B) There is a firewall blocking port `5432`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by editing the `pg_hba.conf`.

1. In the linode instance, navigate to `/var/lib/pgsql/data`.
2. In the directory, open the `pg_hba.conf` and add the following line under the IPv4 local connections

```
host    all             all             <local system's Public IP ADDRESS>/32   md5
```

3. Save the file and restart postgres.
4. Start SSH tunneling to the linode instance
5. Change the host and port in the database details to `127.0.0.1` and the port selected during tunneling. In my case it was `5433`
6. Running the python script now should enable the local system to connect with the postgres server running in the linode instance.

Comment: No you solved it by tunneling through the firewall.

Answer (score 0):

The official [guide](https://www.linode.com/docs/guides/securely-manage-remote-postgresql-servers-with-pgadmin-on-macos-x/)  ( check [here](https://www.linode.com/docs/guides/how-to-install-use-postgresql-ubuntu-20-04/#accessing-postgresql-remotely) for Windows )
suggests using an SSH Tunnel to access Postgresql remotely.

```
ssh -f -L 5433:127.0.0.1:5432 username@remote-host -N
```